# Show homomorphism $f \mapsto f^2 $ injective but not surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $R=\mathbb F_2[x]$, let $\psi:R \to R$ given by $f \mapsto f^2 $ be homomorphism.
>
> How can I show that $\psi$ is injective but not surjective?

Could I show that the image of $\psi$ does not equal $R$ for surjectivity? If so, how can I explicitly demonstrate this?

For injectivity could I show $\ker(\psi) = \{0_R\}$?

EDIT: Extra question, am I correct in thinking $\mathbb F_2[x]$ is isomorphic to a proper subring of itself? Is there a way to show this using $\psi$ above and the first isomorphism theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the definition for injectivity.

For surjectivity, I think it is sufficient to show that there is no $a \in R$ with $a^2 = x$.

Comment: For injectivity it is worth noticing that $\psi$ is linear, so one just need to check that there is no polynomial $p$ with $p^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- $\deg(p^2) = \deg(p) + \deg(p) = 2\deg(p)$

**Injectivity:**

The above implies that the kernel is trivial.

**Non-Surjectivity:**

The above implies that odd degree polynomials do not exist in the image.